# I got the error syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm first to ruby, so when i following the Guide(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) I got the error like:

> Started GET "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-07 17:22:36 +0900
>
> SyntaxError (/Users/sookcha/Desktop/Dev/CSap/app/models/question.rb:3: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
>   /Users/sookcha/Desktop/Dev/CSap/app/models/question.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
>       validates :name,  :presence => true
>      ^):
>     app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:2:in `'
>
> Rendered /Users/sookcha/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.1ms)
>     Rendered /Users/sookcha/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.1ms)
>     Rendered /Users/sookcha/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (10.7ms)

when I refresh the page, i got a different error below:

```
Started GET "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-07 17:22:40 +0900

NoMethodError (undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass):
```

My code is

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :content, :name, :title
validates :name,  :presence => true
validates :title, :presence => true,
                  :length => { :minimum => 5 }

end
```

What's wrong with my code?

EDIT

When I insert
`# encoding: utf-8,` in my code,
I got a different error like:

`/Users/sookcha/Desktop/Dev/CSap/app/models/question.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' validates :name, :presence => true ^ /Users/sookcha/Desktop/Dev/CSap/app/models/question.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end :length => { :minimum => 5 } ^):`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) in your code:

```
validates :name,  :presence => true
                ^
               here
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine, I bet your editor is inserting a non-standard tab somewhere. Place this at the top of your model file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

It's a magic comment that instructs ruby to interpret any non-ascii strings or literals as UTF-8.

Comment: I got a different error /Users/sookcha/Desktop/Dev/CSap/app/models/question.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' validates :name, :presence => true ^ /Users/sookcha/Desktop/Dev/CSap/app/models/question.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end :length => { :minimum => 5 } ^):