# "unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input" when defining encoding as UTF-8 in Rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, ruby-2.0

### The problem

I have a Rails 3.2.13 project where some source files contain strings with non-ASCII characters (mainly åäö).

When I deployed to the staging server, everything failed in a storm of encoding errors. Thanks to StackOverflow I found and installed the [magic_encoding](https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding) gem to add the `# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-` comment to every source file.

Now I get this error when I try to load  page:

> .../app/helpers/venues_helper.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

### What I've tried

I realised I had been using Ruby 2.0.0 on my development machine and 1.9.3 on the staging server (I know, I know), causing the whole UTF-8 problem when deploying to arise in the first place. Maybe switching to 1.9.3 in my dev environment would help? Nope.

I entertained the thought that I actually had gotten an `end` in the wrong place. So I removed everyhting but:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
module VenuesHelper
end
```

Nope. Same error.

I tried replacing every whitespace character in the file [in case one of them was something else than a space or newline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10928310/454094). Nope.

I tried removing the magic comment, in case it was causing the problem. **Success!** I don't get this syntax error anymore, but I'm stuck with my breaking staging server that I set out to fix in the first place. :C

### What I'm hoping for

An explanation to what is causing this and a way to avoid it in the future.

All my other files are okay with the magic comment being present, this particular file fails even when there is no actual content. What the hell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riiight. I re-wrote the entire file by hand, and apparently there **was** a non-printable character in the line `module VenuesHelper` that wrecked havoc.

At least everything works now, and `git diff` is telling me that this specific line, while seemingly unchanged, differs.

I think I'll have to post a new question on how to best identify non-breaking spaces and the like in places where you don't want them...

Comment: Just in case someone else runs into this problem, I had accidentally left an unfinished line in my code that I hadn't noticed. Something to the effect of: `@user = User.` The period after user created the error.